# send notifications to user in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i try to send notifications in asp.net

when admin login and click on add message then this message send to user when user log in then pop up notications appear

here i try

```
<input class="add_message" type="text" value="type your message" name="add_message">
</input>
 <input type="button" value="add message" 
    önclick="sNotify.addToQueue($(".add_message").attr("value"))"></input>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
   sNotify.addToQueue("You can add your message here."); 

   sNotify.timeOpen = 10;
```

this code in try in approval.aspx

and this is the link where i get concept ..plz see this link i implement and add javascript in js folder and try to code it but when i click on add message then pop can not appear...?? how i do this?
[link](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/snotify-easy-notifications-in-jquery/)

any help?

head section code

```
<link href='css/sNotify.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/sNotify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this is css

```
 body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

.sNotify_message {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    right: 0px;
    top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
}

.sNotify_close {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

this is js

```
var sNotify = {

    timeOpen: 10,   //change this number to the amount of second you want the message opened

    queue: new Array(),
    closeQueue: new Array(),

    addToQueue: function(msg) {
        sNotify.queue.push(msg);
    },

    createMessage: function(msg) {

        //create HTML + set CSS
        var messageBox = $("<div><span class=\"sNotify_close\">x</span>" + msg + "</div>").prependTo("body");
        $(messageBox).addClass("sNotify_message");

        sNotify.enableActions(messageBox);
        sNotify.closeQueue.push(0);

        return $(messageBox);

    },

    loopQueue: function() {
        //pop queue
        if (sNotify.queue.length > 0) {

            var messageBox = sNotify.createMessage(sNotify.queue[0]);
            sNotify.popMessage(messageBox);

            sNotify.queue.splice(0,1);

        }

        //close queue
        if (sNotify.closeQueue.length > 0) {
            var indexes = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < sNotify.closeQueue.length; i++) {
                sNotify.closeQueue[i]++;

                if (sNotify.closeQueue[i] > sNotify.timeOpen) {
                    indexes.push(i);
                }
            }

            //now close them
            for (var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                var buttons = $(".sNotify_close");
                sNotify.closeMessage($(buttons[($(buttons).length - indexes[i]) - 1]));
                sNotify.closeQueue.splice(indexes[i],1);    
            }

        }

    },

    enableActions: function(messageBox) {
        //reset timer when hovering
        $(messageBox).hover(
            function() {
                var index = ($(this).nextAll().length - 1);
                sNotify.closeQueue[index] = -1000;
            },
            function() {
                var index = ($(this).nextAll().length - 1);
                sNotify.closeQueue[index] = 0;
            }
        );

        //enable click close button
        $(messageBox).find(".sNotify_close").click(function() {
            sNotify.closeMessage(this);
        });
    },

    popMessage: function(messageBox) {
        $(messageBox).css({
            marginRight: "-290px",
            opacity: 0.2,
            display: "block"
        });

        var height = parseInt($(messageBox).outerHeight()) + parseInt($(messageBox).css("margin-bottom"));

        $(".sNotify_message").next().each(function() {
            var topThis = $(this).css("top");

            if (topThis == "auto") {
                topThis = 0;
            }

            var newTop = parseInt(topThis) + parseInt(height);

            $(this).animate({
                top: newTop + "px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 600
            });
        });

        $(messageBox).animate({
            marginRight: "20px",
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 800);
    },

    closeMessage: function(button) {
        var height = parseInt($(button).parent().outerHeight()) + parseInt($(button).parent().css("margin-bottom"));

        $(button).parent().nextAll().each(function() {
            var topThis = $(this).css("top");

            if (topThis == "auto") {
                topThis = 0;
            }

            var newTop = parseInt(topThis) - parseInt(height);

            $(this).animate({
                top: newTop + "px"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 300
            });
        });

        $(button).parent().hide(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }

}

setInterval("sNotify.loopQueue()", 900);
```

this is the button click code

```
<input class="add_message" type="text" value="type your message" name="add_message"></input>

<input type="button" value="add message" onclick="sNotify.addToQueue($(".add_message").attr("value"))"></input>
```

suppose there is two forms abc.aspx and def.aspx form and i done code in abc.aspx and it works and  here when admin press button  then pop up's appear in abc.aspx  page but i want here when admin press button then notifications send to def.aspx form which is user form..

Comment: Can you share contents inside <head> section. If possible just post your full version of code.

Comment: @susai plaese check my update question

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this should be a comment but don't have enough rep yet

first thing I notice is onclick as a ö instead of o - it could be as simple as that but as susai said - more code would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You have used sNotify plugin in your admin page(say abc.aspx). As you said, you didn't implement that in user page (say def.aspx). The sNotify plugin don't populate notification to other pages automatically where it doesn't implemented.

To achieve your objective, save all notifications in admin page. Implement the sNotify plugin in user page. Use server push or pull technology to read saved notifications and add them into sNotify queue so that notification will appear in the user page when admin do operations.

Comment: so how i save notifications... and what do u mean by server push?

Comment: Answering to your first question, Use Database and store them in server. You can fetch it from your user page.  Answering to your 2nd question, server push technology helps server to push data to connected clients automatically without any request from client. Kindly refer websocket - http://www.websocket.org/. Note:It is not mandatory to use server push. You can use server pull i.e. normal request-response also. According to your need, server push suits.